# ¿Cómo agregar valores a un Spinner en Android?

Tags: java, android

Tengo esto en el archivo xml de mi activity, pero no sé cómo agregarle valores.

```
<Spinner
android:id="@id/spinner"
... 
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obten la referencia:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

crea un adapter que sea alimentado por un arreglo de elementos:

```
String[] datos = new String[] {"C#", "Java", "Python", "R", "Go"};
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, datos);
```

al final solo defines el `Adapter` a tu `Spinner` por medio del método [setAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)):

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

Incluso puedes también definir los valores dentro de `styles.xml`, por ejemplo:

```
  <string-array name="datos">
        <item>C#</item>
        <item>Java</item>
        <item>Python</item>
        <item>R</item>
        <item>Go</item>
    </string-array>
```

y cargas de esta forma los valores al `Adapter`.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.datos, R.layout.spiner_item);
```

defines el `Adapter` a tu `Spinner` :

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Falta mencionar que tienes dos opciónes de crear un `ArrayAdapter`, con un arreglo (como en la respuesta de Jorgesys) y con un `List`.

Ambos tienen su sentido. Si trabajas con datos inmutables (o sea el contenido del spinner no cambia) es preferible de usar el arreglo, porque tiene mejor performancia. Si quieres construir un adapter en que se pueden modificar los contenidos mostrados, tienes que instar el `ArrayAdapter`con una lista:

```
List<String> listSpinner = Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listSpinner);
```